# Persistent SSH port forward without public keys

Tags: ssh, security, password

**Problem**

I haven't found a solution to run an SSH port forward in a reliable and persistent fashion, when the server you are connecting to does **not** support public-key authentication.

**Question**

What is the most reasonable way to keep a persistent SSH port forward alive when a password is required?  Taking into account security and reliability (I realise it is not ideal). I'm happy for it to need a password on start (i.e. not persistent over server reboots, this should prevent an actual script from having a plaintext password), but I need it to be reliable over disconnections.

**Motiviation**

The server I wish to connect to is behind a series of firewalls, and I am using local SSH port forwarding to expose a web-server to the public Internet. I am currently using standard port forwarding, but getting 'broken pipe' errors every few days and I want it to auto-restart the connection on these types of failures.

**Attempts**

- I have tried to use [AutoSSH](http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/) but it seems to assume you have public-key authentication. I have not been successful in getting it work with some kind of password authentication.
- I have tried using [sshpass](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/), but then I've been unsuccessful at getting the port forwarding to work with this. I think it might be getting confused by the welcome message the SSH server gives.

**Why can't I enable public-key authentication?**

It has been setup by design by IT to require a password, for policy reasons. I do not have root access to the server and cannot change it. I'd like to use public-key authentication, but I am stuck with what I have.

**Ideas**

- Maybe using something like [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/), and building my own script solution, but it doesn't sound great.

Answer (score 0):

The author of the question provided the following work-around solution:

> **Update - Work-around solution**
>
> This isn't really a solution to the given question, but it did solve my original problem. I ended up using a reverse proxy instead of a local proxy, this allowed me to use public keys and autossh.
>
> ```
> autossh -M 20000 -nNT -R *:80:localhost:80 user@host.com
> ```